# SSH doesn't work with my key for an user but works for another

Tags: ssh, authentication, ubuntu-12.04, ssh-keys

**Server (Ubuntu):**

`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (on `issue-user`):

- just one public key on one single line. No extra lines! No comments!
- correct user/group owner
- 644 rights

**Local Machine (Windows 7):**

- works with the `git` user on the same server
- doesn't work with the `issue-user`
- the key pairs match

**After running `ssh issue-user@domain.com -vvv`:**

```
debug2: key: /c/***/***/.ssh/identity (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/***/***/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/***/***/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/***/***/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /c/***/***/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /c/***/***/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/***/***/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/***/***/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

**The `id_rsa` key file is definitely there: `/c/***/***/.ssh/id_rsa`**

Comment: Can you compare permissions on keys, parent directories and home directories of the two mentioned users? My server (Gentoo) explicitly forbids publicly readable keys. Permissions on home must be o-rwx, on .ssh directory holding keys permissions are 0700 and on the key file authorized_keys permissions are 0640. SSH would log such problem into auth.log (depending on your syslog configuration).

Comment: @AlešKrajník - it works. thanks. you can provide as answer if you want accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in permissions on keys, parent directories and/or home directories of the two mentioned users. My server (Gentoo) explicitly forbids publicly readable keys.

Permissions on home should be o-rwx, on .ssh directory holding keys permissions should be 0700 and on the key file authorized_keys permissions should be 0640.

SSHD would log such problem into auth.log (depending on your syslog configuration).